# The ordered and unordered sequence

Tags: java

I would like to write a program that reads a sequence of integer numbers and outputs true if the sequence is ordered (in asc or desc order), otherwise, false.

The sequence ends with 0. Do not consider this number as a part of the sequence. The sequence always has at least one number (excluding 0).

my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        int b;
        boolean asc = true;
        boolean dsc = true;
        a = read.nextInt();
        while (a == 0) {
            a = read.nextInt();
        }
        while (true) {
            b = read.nextInt();
            if (b == 0) {
                break;
            }
            dsc = dsc && a >= b;
            asc = asc && a <= b;
            if (asc || dsc == false) {
                break;
            }
            a = b;
        }
        System.out.println(asc || dsc);
    }
}
```

Test input: 1 2 5 5 2 3 0

Correct output: false

My code output: true

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the parsing precedence of the operators `||` and `==`? Be careful about precedence in case that matters here.

Comment: I think you mean `if (!asc && !dsc)`

Comment: asc || dsc will always be true! You are checking if asc is true or dsc is true. One of them is always true so your program will give you always true. So modify your System.out.println(...) code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your if statement `if (asc || dsc == false)` which most likely should be `if (!asc && !dsc)`.

Result would be this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        int b;
        boolean asc = true;
        boolean dsc = true;
        a = read.nextInt();
        while (a == 0) {
            a = read.nextInt();
        }
        while (true) {
            b = read.nextInt();
            if (b == 0) {
                break;
            }
            dsc = dsc && a >= b;
            asc = asc && a <= b;
            if (!asc && !dsc) {
                break;
            }
            a = b;
        }
        System.out.println(asc || dsc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make that `!asc && !dsc`

Comment: This outputs true for `1 2 3 4 5 2 0`

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition before the `break` statement is wrong. When you write

```
if (asc || dsc == false)
```

it will check if `asc` is `true` or if `dsc` is `false`, which means that if the first number's ascending, it will immediately break, and if it isn't, it will break the first time the sequence isn't descending.

What you should put there is `!asc && !dsc`, which will get you the output you want. It will only break if both `asc` and `dsc` are false, and your sequence has no order.